# Calling javascript from the code behind gives error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-canvas

I am using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to call JavaScript Function From Code behind. It works properly for simple functions in javascript. But it does now work properly if the function in javascript is having object. For example

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "window-script", "surface.plot();", True)
```

In javascript i have function like

```
Surface.prototype.plot = function(x, y, z)
 {
   \\code here
 }
```

Now the surface is an object in javascript. So i think the call from the asp.net code not working. When i checked the object has become NULL. So everything in that javascript goes wrong. So how to solve it?

Comment: Did you check casing of object names ? Surface vs surface

Comment: @KartheekN yes i have used it properly i think.because i define object as var surface = new Surface();    Also while calling function i have used surface.plot();  Is that correct?

Comment: That looks alright, however from the sample you provided above, plot function expects three parameters which are not being passed. That might be a reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "window.onload=function(){parent.location.reload(true);}", true);
```